# Magento 2 fetch PO number from checkout page into my custom table?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, checkout-page

I have enabled the `Purchase Order payment` method from magento backend.
The PO payment method takes a input field data and stores into `Sales_order_payment` table as `po_number`.
I want to fetch the same value of the input field after place order and store it into my custom table.

Currently I am using the following in my observer for `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event.

`protected $_dataObject;`

`\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data,`

`$this->_dataObject = $data;`

`$po_number = $this->_dataObject->getPoNumber();`

The current code is not giving me the PO number.
Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `po_number` from Payment method object.

```
namespace YourCompany\YourModule\Observer;

use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class HelloWorld implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }


    public function execute(Observer $observer ) {

        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

        if (count($orderIds)) {
            $orderId = $orderIds[0];
            $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
            $poNumber = $order->getPayment()->getPoNumber();
        }
    }
}
```